# Can't able to run Groovy script in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

When I execute the groovy script in JSR223 Post processor,I get the following error.The script works  fine with earlier version but when upgraded to Jmeter5.4.2 it throws this error.

```
021-12-20 19:47:02,491 WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: AESUtil for class: Script4
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:162) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Groovy.execute(Groovy.java:120) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:138) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:113) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:100) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:280) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.getPath(HTTPSamplerBase.java:508) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.getUrl(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1079) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_201]
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: AESUtil for class: Script4
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:159) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: AESUtil for class: Script4
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307) ~[groovy-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at Script4.run(Script4.groovy:1) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:159) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You "Can't able to run Groovy script in Jmeter" because you're trying to use `AESUtil` class (whatever it is) and the class is not known to JMeter/Groovy

In order to be able to use `AESUtil` class you need to put it under [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (copy the .jar providing the class to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation)

Also looking into dependencies for JMeter 5.4.2 it seems that JMeter uses [groovy version 3.0.7](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.2/gradle.properties#L86) and from your log file it appears that you're having `groovy-all-2.4.16.jar` so I would recommend removing it from JMeter Classpath in order to avoid potential [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)

More information: [How to Reuse Your JMeter Code with JAR Files and Save Time](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-reuse-your-jmeter-code-with-jar-files-and-save-time)